# small issue with ddev - brew - docker

Tags: ddev

just set up a dev laptop but installing ddev has been problematic. followed instructions from docs.docker.com, ddev.readthedocs.com, and Mike Anello's book for DDEV LOCAL.

An unusual and undocumented bit of installation is when I tried to run brew initially, my Ubuntu 18.04 complained to me to install linuxbrew-wrapper so I did. Then the brew worked properly.

The situation is this: I cannot run ddev unless the docker container is stopped. Looking in /bin and /Cellar shows most of the executables have myname:docker as owner/group but ddev, hello, patchelf are myname:myname owner/group.

Should I chown those files to myname:docker owner/group to be able to run them while the container is live?

or

Am I supposed to shut off the container for running ddev?

Solution (ymmv)
Part 1

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install     apt-transport-https     ca-certificates     curl     gnupg-agent     software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
sudo add-apt-repository    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
sudo docker run hello-world
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose
docker-compose --version
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
newgrp docker
```

Part 2

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken
echo 'eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >>~/.profile
eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
echo 'eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >>~/.bashrc
source .bashrc
```

Part 3

```
brew
brew install gcc
brew tap drud/ddev && brew install ddev
mkcert --install
```

Comment: Something is really wrong. Did you install docker as described in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/docker_installation/#linux-installation-docker-ce ? Did you do the post-install steps of adding yourself to the docker group? (You usually have to log out and log back in after that).  There isn't any required chowning in the whole process.

Comment: All linuxbrew does in its install process is get you the ddev binary (which doesn't require special privileges) and most likely the docker-compose binary. I usually `brew tap drud/ddev && brew install ddev docker-compose` since docker-compose doesn't come with the docker package.

Comment: yes to your question about sequence of installation. this problem did not happen on the other laptop setup 6 months ago and runs perfectly. I'll do more digging. Additional info is that bin/ has 100s of commands that I did not install manually.

Comment: On 18.04 those instructions tell you to uninstall any remnants of docker that may have been installed with the operating system and then install all from docker's repo. The ddev instructions give you a magic docker command to run to see if everything is working.

Comment: Thx rfay. Will remove all and start from scratch. Must have either missed a step or did something out of sequence.

Comment: Were you successful? Happy to help if you need more help.

Comment: I was finally successful but it was convoluted and different than the linked resources made out. Installing brew properly was the  snafu for the whole setup here. Thanks for checking back.

Comment: It would be kind and appropriate if you'd share here how you solved your problem, because the whole reason that we do Stack Overflow is that the next person to come along gets the benefit of your experience.

Comment: There were many problems with al of my back and forth install attempts. Cleaned everything out and off to get back to scratch. Installed Docker CE, installed Composer, installed docker-composer. Then this is ht eonly thing that worked for me (ymmv)